# How to format the cron url when driving to a shell script

Tags: bash

I have a `shell` program name `myshellscript.sh` and not having any luck with getting it to run by `cron`. Can anyone see what i am missing.. Runs perfect when using the shell terminal.. but just don't have the URL right yet to fire it off.

```
php /home/myuser/public_html/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/myshellscript.sh
```

Here is my latest attempt that does not work.. I have used WGET vice PHP before with a full URL but just have no idea if I am onthe right track or not..

Comment: Are you interpreting a shell script using `php`? If not, then use absolute path to `php` inside `crontab`

Comment: No php has nothing to do with it.. just that i am so used to php i tried that but what i have is a basic shell script sitting in the script dierectorry on the server waiting for a push from tthe cron..and not sure what the absolute path to it is.. with php i could use the __FILE__ command but not sure how to get it with this.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific error message beyond you saying that it does not work, we can only speculate on 'common issues' that prevent cron jobs from running, i.e.:  user and file permissions, missing path/environmental info, etc.

Check man page for cron - note information about setting path and environment.
Some operating systems support setting environment option directly in your 'crontab file'; others may require using full paths to executables, or perhaps allow you to 'refine' the PATH variable in your script...

Try capturing/logging cron 'errors', i.e.

```
*/5 * * * * /some_path/your_script.sh 2>&1 >> /tmp/cron.script.log
```

The above line well send both STD-out and STD-error to the file shown, and, it will 'run' every 5 minutes.

:)
Dale